# How to migrate app from sdk 8 to newer versions?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-2.2-froyo

I've been developing an app (min sdk 8) that uses the physical menu buton for almost everything into the app. Recently I've bought a new cellphone and I realize that it doesn't have a physical menu button, compromising the usage of my app. I don't want to change the min sdk version, what is the best way to migrate to newer versions? I've taken a look into `Action Bar` but I don't know if I need to reimplement everything I've made so far (removing the logic that uses physical menu button) or if I let how it is and just implement new logic that uses action bar.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to take a look at ActionBarActivity from the support library. They have similar callback like onCreateOptionMenu, onOptionMenuSelected etc. So it is not that hard to make the transition in terms of the menu button you talked about.

Answer (score 1):

Don't worry about action bar, you can use v4 or v7 support jars which will work on lower versions as well.
Hard menu button is just to give options menu. If you use action bar you will see three dots on the right side which indicates options menu.

Comment: ActionBarSherlock has been deprecated by the maintainer, who suggests using the support library ActionBarActivity instead